# How to change a list of true/false strings to a list of True/false bools that can be used in a function - python

Tags: python, string, list, replace, boolean-logic

I've collected a list of True or false items from a file and converted them into a list of strings:

```
status = ['True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'False']
```

But I need to input these into a function that only accepts the boolean value of each, but this makes all these strings all be true due to actually having a value inside the string.

In short, here is what I need to convert to:

```
status = [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False]
```

So I've tried a few different loop structures as such:

```
for v in status:
    if v == "True":
        v = True
    if v == "False":
        v = False
```

However this still gives back the strings in the list, or I've had the list values be deleted.
Thanks for any help everybody.

Comment: `booleans = [item=='True' for item in status]`

Comment: ```status = list(map(lambda x: x=='True', status))```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You loop does not actually store the values back to the list. You need to store them:

```
booleans = []

for v in status:
    if v == "True":
        booleans.append(True)
    else:
        booleans.append(False)

status = booleans
```

Or in one line:

```
status = [item == "True" for item in status]
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
status = list(map(lambda x: x=='True', status))
```